# Таймер java

Tags: android, java

Нашел дельную статейку - [тык](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/handler/android-timer-example/).
Но хочу больше разобраться в таймерах, поэтому поставил задачу, что по достижению, к примеру, отсчета, равному 20 минутам, будет происходить любое действие, которое я задам.
Как это можно реализовать? (Да, нуб, да, читаю статьи, но на каждый случай статей нету.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно и без таймера.

```
new Handler().postDelayed (new Runnable() { public void run() { foo() }, 20 * 1000);
```

Хэндлер выполнит действие (Runnable) со смещением во времени 20 * 1000 миллисекунд.

В статье тоже используется Handler, а не таймер.

Информация по [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). Информация про [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html).

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() { public void run() { foo(); }, 20 * 1000);
```

Таймер запустит функцию foo() через 20 секунд. По аналогии с хэндлером.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, разобрался, более или менее)

Comment: @alex11, лучше уж более :)

Answer (score 1):

Вот такой есть таймер

```
new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {       
       public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {          
           System.out.println("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);      
       }

       public void onFinish() {         
           //Action!!! 
       }   
}.start();
```

Comment: Как я понял, то в этом примере, таймер доходит до конца отсчета и потом выполняет действие, тоже полезно, но мне немного другое надо было, то есть чтобы время увеличивалось, а по достижению определенного времени выполнялось действие, похоже, но не то. Но все равно спасибо, буду знать)